# Css reflection error after hover

Tags: html, css

In my web site there's and css error after hover on social menu icons. Tried with firebug to find certain hover css. But there is no css interacting to create that effect. I want to remove that effect. Can someone guide me to find the problem in this css

[Link removed]

Error is when I hover on to the social icons there is an reflection.

Comment: where is your code and what you tried [answer]

Comment: I think you wanted to post [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If i add code here there will be huge code. Thats why I provided the link. Error is when hover on the twitter social icon its shows reflection

Comment: @Dan The website you provided still loading in my briwser and you should give us more detail, or some code...

Answer (score 0):

Search for :hover in your css file.
Hover in CSS is used like that:

```
a:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

So if you search :hover on CSS; you will find the rule that you want to disable.

Edit: I see that in yor base.css, is that color that you want to disable? (line 99)

```
a:hover, a:focus { color: #000; }
```

If yes, just remove that line (it will remove the focus effect too on links)

Comment: @Dan remove the hover that you find in css/roller.css and css/flexslider.css but (without seing your webpage (still loading for me)), it could be on roller.css: line 84, 133, and 183

Answer (score 0):

in your **roller.css** search this code, it is giving your social icon opacity

```
.social div a:hover,
.app_store div a:hover{
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

so replace it with this code

```
.app_store div a:hover{
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a css problem: as you can see this problem disappear when you scroll down and then back to the top. So it's from some jquery code on the buttons.
I tested too removing the mute button adding display: none; it still appears so it's really from the buttons

Comment: any suggestion which button?

Comment: I think its causing by fallingsnaw.js. But cant find exact point to correct the error

Comment: all buttons: problem appears only on the margin. but seems your problem is solved